# How to connect to LinkedIn using LinkedIn API from Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, linkedin-api, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to get the number of followers to my company's LinkedIn page by using the following API call from Power BI Desktop, using OData Feed.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:000000000?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember

When connecting, I'm asked to choose an access method, which includes Anonymous, Windows, Basic, Web API or Organizational Account. My best guess is that I should use Web API, and when I click this option, it asks me for a Key. Where can I find this key?

Or, am I doing it totally wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

## linkedin

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I know there is no API and provided from Linkeding and no out of box connector from PowerBI for Linkedin.

What at most you can do so is download your connections as CSV file and  use that for PowerBI,
Here is an article which will describe you how to achieve this.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-do-free-linkedin-connection-analytic-power-bi-desktop-pawar/

Answer (score 0):

You should first create an app in https://www.linkedin.com/developers
And an id and Key will be generated automatically.
Or you can connect LinkedIn to power bi using A Third-party connector if that helps.